# Wait for dropdown value to be selected before moving on with the script - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am selecting a value from dropdown.

```
WebElement policyDD = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("policyDropdown")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("policyDropdown"))));
    policyDD.click();
    WebElement policyVal = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("selectPolicy")));
    policyVal.click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("policyVerify"))));
```

On executing `policyVal.click();` it takes about 4-5 seconds for value to be selected (there is some loading execution on clicking the dropdown value)

My next command is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("ratingOnReviewPage"))).click();
```

From the above command `By.xpath(OR.getProperty("ratingOnReviewPage"))` is already present on the screen. So it immediately executes it and doesn't wait for 4-5 seconds for value to be selected successfully from the dropdown.

`By.xpath(OR.getProperty("ratingOnReviewPage"))` element reloads/refreshes once dropdown value is selected (after 4-5 sec)

This fails my test. How can I create a script where the last command waits for dropdown value to be selected successfully?

Comment: Check the drop down options Count, or wait until an option exists inside the aforementioned drop down.

Comment: @RyanWilson
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("policyVerify")))); 

this is waiting for the option to exist in dropdown

Comment: Then if the issue is waiting for it to be selected, wait for the selected index of the drop down to equal the index of the option.